# DNS: Can master server be non-authoritative?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system

We have about 10 domains in 10 different countries and we want to setup some centralized DNS management. Basically we have this design in mind (all servers are RHEL, with bind as DNS):

Have 1 master DNS server hidden, not accessible from internet, which contains zone files for all these domains, so that we can change everything on 1 place. Have slave DNS servers in each country to which these zones are respectively replicated to from master server.

The weird part of this design as I see it, is that only slave servers would be in DMZ and accessible from internet, and only them would be authoritative, having NS record for each such domain.

Does it make any sense? Is it even possible to have a master server for a domain that isn't considered authoritative as it doesn't itself have NS record? (there is no point in having NS record for server that's not visible from internet I guess).

Comment: [SE actually has a pretty nice system for these things](https://github.com/StackExchange/dnscontrol)

Comment: What makes you think the hidden master won't be authoritative for the domains? Being authoritative has nothing to do with whether there's an NS record listing the server. It just comes from whether it loads the zone contents statically versus caching it with recursive queries.

Comment: Hidden masters are a very common configuration in large organizations. There's nothing wrong with the design you're planning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, there is nothing wrong with your design, except for the fact that you are using only one master - you need to have some redundancy. With two or three hidden masters, which are always in sync - the slave servers can refresh their zones even if one or two masters are down.

Many large organizations actually don't want to expose their DNS servers, as they don't want to deal with the headache of DDOSing and global availability etc. What they end up doing is use third party DNS providers such as Dyn or UltraDNS to expose the NS records for their domains, these NS records are slave name servers from third party. Internally the organization will keep its own hidden master servers, make dns changes in those server internally and then have the slave servers from the DNS service providers pull the latest changes. Any external users requests go to the slave name server managed by the third party.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely valid solution, some ilustrations and examples are [here](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch4/#stealth)